# CanvasJS Strange format of Time on x-Axis

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web

I created this diagram with canvasJS. The X-axis is supposed to show the time of the day in hours. Right now, the time looks like 1:0, 3:0. But I would like to have it like 01:00, 03:00. How can I fix that?
Furthermore, the Y-axis does not set automatically. I would like to have only the value area in which points are set. 
Thank you very much!

[image: Chart JS Diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the axisX object, the value should be: `axisX: {valueFormatString: "HH:DD"}`